# Email attachment not working in drupal site

Tags: php, drupal, smtp, phpmailer

after upgrade of drupal 9 and php 8 version i am unable to send attachment mail. we are getting following issue

PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception: Could not access file:   in PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->addAttachment() (line 3182 of vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: That syntax suggests you're not actually using PHPMailer at all; PHPMailer doesn't work that way. We need to see your sending code.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, it means your script cannot access the file that you asked it to attach.

I recommend checking the ownership and permissions of the file in question.

Comment: i have checked the permission on the same file opened in browser working fine

Comment: Is the script being run as the same user as your web server?

Comment: yes, acquia cloud hosting uploaded files available in the following \docroot\sites\default\pdf\ample.pdf and any idea how to check the ownership and permissions in acquia cloud

Comment: Sorry, no idea about that